# Building a thread-safe GUID increment'er

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, guid

In my below code, I'm locking the guid, to try and make it thread safe.
With my example application, I will get a "duplicate key" about every 10 times I run the program.  Aka, I get a duplicate, which is not what I need.

Is there anyway to make the ".NextGuid" thread safe?

```
using System;    
namespace MyConsoleOne.BAL
{
    public class GuidStore
    {
        private static object objectlock = new object();    
        private Guid StartingGuid { get; set; }    
        private Guid? LastGuidHolder { get; set; }    
        public GuidStore(Guid startingGuid)
        {
            this.StartingGuid = startingGuid;
        }

        public Guid? GetNextGuid()
        {
            lock (objectlock)
            {
                if (this.LastGuidHolder.HasValue)
                {
                    this.LastGuidHolder = Increment(this.LastGuidHolder.Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    this.LastGuidHolder = Increment(this.StartingGuid);
                }
            }    
            return this.LastGuidHolder;
        }

        private Guid Increment(Guid guid)
        {    
            byte[] bytes = guid.ToByteArray();    
            byte[] order = { 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 6, 7, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3 };    
            for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
            {
                if (bytes[order[i]] == byte.MaxValue)
                {
                    bytes[order[i]] = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    bytes[order[i]]++;
                    return new Guid(bytes);
                }
            }    
            throw new OverflowException("Guid.Increment failed.");
        }
    }
}

using MyConsoleOne.BAL;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyConsoleOne
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GuidStore gs = new GuidStore(Guid.NewGuid());

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                Dictionary<Guid, int> guids = new Dictionary<Guid, int>();
                Parallel.For(0, 1000, j =>
                {
                    Guid? currentGuid = gs.GetNextGuid();
                    guids.Add(currentGuid.Value, j);
                    Console.WriteLine(currentGuid);
                }); // Parallel.For
            }    
            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to Exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

My code is a combination of:

- [Making Guid properties threadsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647811/making-guid-properties-threadsafe)
- [Increment Guid in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30404965/increment-guid-in-c-sharp)

Since I'm getting "Why not use Guid.NewGuid" questions, I'll provide the reason here:

I have a parent process that has a uniqueidentifier which is created by Guid.NewGuid().  I'll refer to this as the "parent guid".  That parent process will create N number of files.  If I were writing from scratch, I would just append the "N" at the end of the filename.  So if the parent Guid was "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111" for example, I would write files

```
"11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111_1.txt"
"11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111_2.txt"
"11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111_3.txt"
```

, etc, etc.  However, via the existing "contract" with the client ::: the filename must have a (unique) Guid in it and not have that "N" (1,2,etc,etc) value in the filename (this "contract" has been in existence for years, so its set in stone pretty much).  With the functionality laid out here, I'll be able to keep the "contract", but have file names that are loosely tied to the "parent" Guid (which again the parent is generated by Guid.NewGuid()).  Collision is **NOT** an issue with the filenames (they are put under a distinct folder for the 'process' execution).  Collision is an issue with the "parent" Guid.  But again, that is already handled with Guid.NewGuid.

So with a starting Guid of "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111", I'll be able to write filenames like:

```
OTHERSTUFF_111111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111112_MORESTUFF.txt
OTHERSTUFF_111111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111113_MORESTUFF.txt
OTHERSTUFF_111111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111114_MORESTUFF.txt
OTHERSTUFF_111111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111115_MORESTUFF.txt
OTHERSTUFF_111111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111116_MORESTUFF.txt
OTHERSTUFF_111111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111117_MORESTUFF.txt
OTHERSTUFF_111111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111118_MORESTUFF.txt
OTHERSTUFF_111111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111119_MORESTUFF.txt
OTHERSTUFF_111111111-1111-1111-1111-11111111111a_MORESTUFF.txt
OTHERSTUFF_111111111-1111-1111-1111-11111111111b_MORESTUFF.txt
```

So in my example above, the "parent guid" is represented by "this.StartingGuid"....and then I get "incremented" guid's off of that.

And also.  I can write better unit-tests, because now I will know the filenames ahead of time.

APPEND:

Final Code Version:

```
public class GuidStore
{
    private static object objectlock = new object();

    private static int[] byteOrder = { 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 6, 7, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3 };

    private Guid StartingGuid { get; set; }

    private Guid? LastGuidHolder { get; set; }

    public GuidStore(Guid startingGuid)
    {
        this.StartingGuid = startingGuid;
    }

    public Guid GetNextGuid()
    {
        return this.GetNextGuid(0);
    }

    public Guid GetNextGuid(int firstGuidOffSet)
    {
        lock (objectlock)
        {
            if (this.LastGuidHolder.HasValue)
            {
                this.LastGuidHolder = Increment(this.LastGuidHolder.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                this.LastGuidHolder = Increment(this.StartingGuid);
                for (int i = 0; i < firstGuidOffSet; i++)
                {
                    this.LastGuidHolder = Increment(this.LastGuidHolder.Value);
                }
            }

            return this.LastGuidHolder.Value;
        }
    }

    private static Guid Increment(Guid guid)
    {
        var bytes = guid.ToByteArray();
        var canIncrement = byteOrder.Any(i => ++bytes[i] != 0);
        return new Guid(canIncrement ? bytes : new byte[16]);
    }
}
```

and UnitTests:

```
public class GuidStoreUnitTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetNextGuidSimpleTest()
    {
        Guid startingGuid = new Guid("11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111");
        GuidStore gs = new GuidStore(startingGuid);


        List<Guid> guids = new List<Guid>();

        const int GuidCount = 10;

        for (int i = 0; i < GuidCount; i++)
        {
            guids.Add(gs.GetNextGuid());
        }

        Assert.IsNotNull(guids);
        Assert.AreEqual(GuidCount, guids.Count);
        Assert.IsNotNull(guids.FirstOrDefault(g => g == new Guid("11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111112")));
        Assert.IsNotNull(guids.FirstOrDefault(g => g == new Guid("11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111113")));
        Assert.IsNotNull(guids.FirstOrDefault(g => g == new Guid("11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111114")));
        Assert.IsNotNull(guids.FirstOrDefault(g => g == new Guid("11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111115")));
        Assert.IsNotNull(guids.FirstOrDefault(g => g == new Guid("11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111116")));
        Assert.IsNotNull(guids.FirstOrDefault(g => g == new Guid("11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111117")));
        Assert.IsNotNull(guids.FirstOrDefault(g => g == new Guid("11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111118")));
        Assert.IsNotNull(guids.FirstOrDefault(g => g == new Guid("11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111119")));
        Assert.IsNotNull(guids.FirstOrDefault(g => g == new Guid("11111111-1111-1111-1111-11111111111a")));
        Assert.IsNotNull(guids.FirstOrDefault(g => g == new Guid("11111111-1111-1111-1111-11111111111b")));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GetNextGuidWithOffsetSimpleTest()
    {
        Guid startingGuid = new Guid("11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111");
        GuidStore gs = new GuidStore(startingGuid);

        List<Guid> guids = new List<Guid>();

        const int OffSet = 10;

        guids.Add(gs.GetNextGuid(OffSet));

        Assert.IsNotNull(guids);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, guids.Count);

        Assert.IsNotNull(guids.FirstOrDefault(g => g == new Guid("11111111-1111-1111-1111-11111111111c")));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GetNextGuidMaxRolloverTest()
    {
        Guid startingGuid = new Guid("ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff");
        GuidStore gs = new GuidStore(startingGuid);

        List<Guid> guids = new List<Guid>();

        const int OffSet = 10;

        guids.Add(gs.GetNextGuid(OffSet));

        Assert.IsNotNull(guids);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, guids.Count);

        Assert.IsNotNull(guids.FirstOrDefault(g => g == Guid.Empty));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GetNextGuidThreadSafeTest()
    {
        Guid startingGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
        GuidStore gs = new GuidStore(startingGuid);

        /* The "key" of the ConcurrentDictionary must be unique, so this will catch any duplicates */
        ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, int> guids = new ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, int>();
        Parallel.For(
            0,
            1000,
            j =>
            {
                Guid currentGuid = gs.GetNextGuid();
                if (!guids.TryAdd(currentGuid, j))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("GuidStore.GetNextGuid ThreadSafe Test Failed");
                }
            }); // Parallel.For
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GetNextGuidTwoRunsProduceSameResultsTest()
    {
        Guid startingGuid = Guid.NewGuid();

        GuidStore gsOne = new GuidStore(startingGuid);

        /* The "key" of the ConcurrentDictionary must be unique, so this will catch any duplicates */
        ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, int> setOneGuids = new ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, int>();
        Parallel.For(
            0,
            1000,
            j =>
            {
                Guid currentGuid = gsOne.GetNextGuid();
                if (!setOneGuids.TryAdd(currentGuid, j))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("GuidStore.GetNextGuid ThreadSafe Test Failed");
                }
            }); // Parallel.For

        gsOne = null;

        GuidStore gsTwo = new GuidStore(startingGuid);

        /* The "key" of the ConcurrentDictionary must be unique, so this will catch any duplicates */
        ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, int> setTwoGuids = new ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, int>();
        Parallel.For(
                0,
                1000,
                j =>
                {
                    Guid currentGuid = gsTwo.GetNextGuid();
                    if (!setTwoGuids.TryAdd(currentGuid, j))
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("GuidStore.GetNextGuid ThreadSafe Test Failed");
                    }
                }); // Parallel.For

        bool equal = setOneGuids.Select(g => g.Key).OrderBy(i => i).SequenceEqual(
                         setTwoGuids.Select(g => g.Key).OrderBy(i => i), new GuidComparer<Guid>());

        Assert.IsTrue(equal);
    }
}

internal class GuidComparer<Guid> : IEqualityComparer<Guid>
{
    public bool Equals(Guid x, Guid y)
    {
        return x.Equals(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Guid obj)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to get a random guid instead on incrementing? Given the fact you plan to use multiple threads it's less probable to have two threads generate the same random guid than two threads incrementing an id from 1 to 2.

Comment: Is there a reason `return` is outside of the `lock`? Looks like if one of threads is suspended just before the return and the next one is allowed into the critical section, the latter modifies the variable and both return the same value.

Comment: why are you not using Guid.NewGuid()? Use the tools .NET gives you.

Comment: As someone who had to unfiretruck a database thanks to someone thinking they'd roll their own GUID algorithm (`public int GetTempGuid() { return Random.Next(10000, 100000); }` - these "globally unique identifiers" happened to collide with real records once we had 10K records in a table) please just do everyone a favour and don't roll-your-own. The algorithms are sophisticated for a reason. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier. If you need a sequential GUID then PInvoke `UuidCreateSequential`.

Comment: I've laid out my reason via an edit in my original question.  I appreciate the concern.  The uuid's are not going in the db.  They guids (here) are for filenames.  Yes, I know about the UuidCreateSequential.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8477664/how-can-i-generate-uuid-in-c-sharp/18337950#18337950

Comment: Have you considered P/Invoking [`UuidCreateSequential`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379322(v=vs.85).aspx)? You can't pick the starting point but it does give you a squential id.

Comment: @ta.speot.is  I would NEVER roll my own Guid maker for putting values in the database.  Yes, that is insane.  I have a simple filename need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two problems here:

1. `Dictionary.Add()` is NOT threadsafe. Use `ConcurrentDictionary.TryAdd()` instead.
2. Your implementation of `GetNextGuid()` has a race condition because your are returning `this.LastGuidHolder` outside the lock, so it could be modified by another thread just before it is returned.

An obvious solution is to move the return inside the lock:

```
public Guid? GetNextGuid()
{
    lock (objectlock)
    {
        if (this.LastGuidHolder.HasValue)
        {
            this.LastGuidHolder = Increment(this.LastGuidHolder.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            this.LastGuidHolder = Increment(this.StartingGuid);
        }

        return this.LastGuidHolder;
    }
}
```

However, I would change the return type to `Guid` - it doesn't seem to serve any purpose to return a `Guid?` - that's something that should be hidden away inside the class:

```
public Guid GetNextGuid()
{
    lock (objectlock)
    {
        if (this.LastGuidHolder.HasValue)
        {
            this.LastGuidHolder = Increment(this.LastGuidHolder.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            this.LastGuidHolder = Increment(this.StartingGuid);
        }

        return this.LastGuidHolder.Value;
    }
}
```

Here's a version of your test method using `ConcurrentDictionary`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    GuidStore gs = new GuidStore(Guid.NewGuid());

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, int> guids = new ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, int>();
        Parallel.For(0, 1000, j =>
        {
            Guid currentGuid = gs.GetNextGuid();
            if (!guids.TryAdd(currentGuid, j))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Duplicate found!");
            }
        }); // Parallel.For
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to Exit");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Having said all that, I cannot understand why you aren't just using `Guid.NewGuid()`...

Comment: +5,000,000,000, use `Guid.NewGuid()`

Comment: The Dictionary was just a quick way to test my code.  It is not "production code". But I'll change to thread-safe-dictionary for testing.  Yeah, on commute into work I realized I should probably put the returnvalue inside the lock.  I use Guid.NewGuid() all the time. My unique caveat I have a "parent" Guid that is generated by Guid.NewGuid().  It will then have several children (xml files).  I'm trying to have the filenames loosely match the "parent" Guid.  It also helps with unit testing, as I can predict the file names a little.